# Count Table Rows in a nested select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, view

I want to create a view that shows statistic of the database like this:

`NumberOfProduct   |   NumberOfUsers  |  NumberOfOnlineUsers`

`45453                  54665             5654645`

**Data source**:

**NumberOfProduct**  - Is Total rows of product table

**NumberOfUsers**  - Number of rows in users table

**NumberOfOnlineUsers** - Is a row value in column called "number" located inside a table called *SiteOverView* where stat_name = 'NumberOfOnlineUsers'

**SiteOverView Table:**

```
     stat_name              |   number

  NumberOfOnlineUsers           5654645    

  NumberOfOfflineUsers          54665 

  NumberOfVisitors              45453
```

I want something like

```
Create View [dbo].[dashboard_stat] 
AS
    SELECT 
         (select count(*) from products) as NumberOfProduct,
         (select count(*) from users) as NumberOfUsers,
         (select number from SiteOverView WHERE stat_name='NumberOfOnlineUsers') as NumberOfOnlineUsers 
FROM (NumberOfOnlineUsers) dashboard_stat
```

but I am struggling to write the statement in write syntactic.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the FROM clause on the main select? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` statements in SQL Sever don't need a `from` clause if you are individually specifying single values for each column being returned.  Because of this your query should work fine without the `from`:

```
create view [dbo].[dashboard_stat] 
as
    select (select count(1) from products) as NumberOfProduct
          ,(select count(1) from users) as NumberOfUsers
          ,(select number
            from SiteOverView
            where stat_name = 'NumberOfOnlineUsers'
            ) as NumberOfOnlineUsers
go
```